# Get records filter based on date time to date comparison possible?

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a scheduled flow where I'm trying to do a get records to get all records where a date time field value is today's date.  E.G. Get records for object account.  Field LastActivitybyHuman__c is a date time field.  I want to get all account records where the date value from that datetime field = todays date.

I'm trying to avoid getting all records and looping through and checking the date value that way.

Is this possible?
[image]

Comment: are you saying that the above is not working?

Comment: correct, it is not working.  I've updated a few test records and when I debug the flow it does not find any records. I've tried equals, starts with, and contains for the operator and none of those work.